# Can you convert an R raw vector representing an RDS file back into an R object without a round trip to disk?

Tags: r, httr, rcurl, raw

I have an RDS file that is uploaded and then download via `curl::curl_fetch_memory()` (via `httr`) - this gives me a raw vector in R.

Is there a way to read that raw vector representing the RDS file to return the original R object?  Or does it always have to be written to disk first?

I have a setup similar to below:

```r
saveRDS(mtcars, file = "obj.rds")
# upload the obj.rds file 
...
# download it again via httr::write_memory()
...

obj
#   [1] 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 ad 56 4f 4c 1c 55 18 1f ca 02 bb ec b2 5d 
# ...
is.raw(obj)
#[1] TRUE
```

It seems `readRDS()` should be used to uncompress it, but it takes a connection object and I don't know how to make a connection object from an R raw vector - `rawConnection()` looked promising but gave:

```r
rawConnection(obj)
#A connection with                           
#description "obj"          
#class       "rawConnection"
#mode        "r"            
#text        "binary"       
#opened      "opened"       
#can read    "yes"          
#can write   "no"     
readRDS(rawConnection(obj))
#Error in readRDS(rawConnection(obj)) : unknown input format
```

Looking through `readRDS` it looks like it uses `gzlib()` underneath but couldn't get that to work with the raw vector object.

If its download via `httr::write_disk()` -> `curl::curl_fetch_disk()` -> `readRDS()` then its all good but this is a round trip to disk and I wondered if it could be optimised for big files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, RDS file streams are gzipped. To read a raw connection you need to manually wrap it into a [`gzcon`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/gzcon.html):

```
con = rawConnection(obj)
result = readRDS(gzcon(con))
```

This works even when the stream *isn’t* gzipped. But unfortunately it fails if a different supported compression method (e.g. `'bzip2'`) was used to create the RDS file. Unfortunately R doesn’t seem to have a `gzcon` equivalent for bzip2 or xz. For those formats, you can manually decompress the data and use `unserialize` instead of `readRDS`:

```
result = unserialize(memDecompress(obj))
```

This works for any data produced by `saveRDS`. It might fail for RDS objects manually created via `memCompress(serialize(…, NULL))`, because `memCompress` is not guaranteed to write a complete compression header that allows detecting the compression method.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and for me, the above answer with `gzcon` did not work, however, I could directly load the raw object into R's memory using the `rawConnection`:

```
load(rawConnection(obj))
```

Comment: Error in load(rawConnection(obj)) : 
  the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection

Comment: This answer loads *RData* data, not *RDS* data. This is a related by different format.